# ExtJs 6.2 ComboBox not send the remote filter

Tags: extjs

I'm working with extjs and strapi. so, I needed to some extra modification over proxy and store. 
I tried to set remote filter combobox with paging according to docs but still can't pass queryParam into querystring!

my codes are in this fiddle:
https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/3511

what is wrong with this code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You remove your `query` parameter in basestore beforeload handler. 
You must merge you new params with default store params. I'm fix it in [my fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/3512)